# ASP.Net Remember Me Functionality

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have an ASP.Net 4.0 Web App.  I'm try to architect a "remember me for 14 days" requirement.  After that period I'd like to force them to re-login.

So my question is how to do this.  I'm thinking of creating my own HttpModule and have it hook into the PostAuthenticateRequest event.  In this event I'll check if the current principal was not authenticated by the normal FormsAuthenticationModule. If not, I would look at the auth ticket returned from the browser and see if it contains my UserData.  My UserData in the ticket would the password they used to successfully authenticate.

My Question:

I'll have to add the password that they used to every response right?  The normal FormsAuthenticationModule changes the ticket that gets sent to the browser continually to keep the user's session alive. So where the best place for me to plug into the pipeline to continually add this to each auth ticket for every response?  And if the FormsAuthenticationModule is already building the ticket, building the cookie, and encrypting it, do I have to override that logic and do that all myself?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't use the built in Membership objects for a while, but I'm quite sure that there will be some property for this. This is a very common scenario. Have you checked the SDK thoroughly?

Answer (score 0):

quote "My UserData in the ticket would the password they used to successfully authenticate."
not sure about the rest, but do not trust any data from the client, cookies can be modified and storing the password in a cookie is BAD, and what about multiuser systems?

Comment: Hey Chris.  The cookie will be encrypted (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt.aspx).  Anyways, what choice do I have?  I don't want to create an auth ticket that expires in 14 days (that wouldn't have a password).  The auth ticket is what ASP.Net uses as its  mechanism to timeout a session so they're only meant to have an expiration datetime that is only, say, 30 minutes into the future.  Let's say that on Monday they logged in and Tuesday we froze their account.  I wouldn't want them to be able to log in for 14 days because of the ticket.

Comment: @sis unless you're reauthenticating on every request, you'd have the same problem if they just didn't close their browser for the 14 days (I've had tabs open for over a month personally).  If you are reauthenticating then you can also check that the account isn't frozen during that time.